# Not getting the $200 credit for Google Maps, on one account only

Tags: google-maps, billing

I don't know if this is the place to ask, but this is where Google has sent me via a Support link within its Maps Console.

I run a web development company, I have loads of sites using Google Maps, I don't think anyone is charged and so I guess they must be within the $200 credit.

There is one site I manage though which is being billed. I set a daily limit of 1p to make sure I dont spend much on it, but I guess when it reaches the limit my maps may break.

Thing is, its a really low visited site. The maps API has been called only 47 times in the past 30 days.

So it seems to me this one account is not getting a $200 credit. Does anyone know why this may be, or what other issue it could be?

Thanks

Comment: `this is where Google has sent me via a Support link within its Maps Console` - not really [this time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376575/11683), it does [say](https://developers.google.com/maps/support) "Get answers to *technical* questions from other Maps Platform developers"

Comment: This is the page, first link direct to here. The support page is linked to from a page about billing  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support?hl=en_US. I can see further down it does then say for technical (cant see it right away on my laptop), but not at the top by the link, so I just clicked that. I do find Google terrible for documentation and UX, they are really bad, very confusing. Not good Google just direct people to such a generic platform for help with their products. I have now raised a case via the 3rd support method in the list.

Answer (score 4):

After a discussion with Google to clear up confusion... the $200 credit is in fact being applied. The issue is the billing section in Google does not actually show the $200 credit in the statement, and so its not clear that any cost is being deducted from the $200, but in fact it is.

Another issue is I set a budget of 1p in order to not spend anything. But this  budget is taken from the $200 credit also, so when I received an alert saying you have spent your budget of 1p it was in fact 1p from the $200 credit.

Google's statement and documentation is not clear, but I hope this clears it up for others.